# completeMigration on Team in MS Graph API (/beta) suddenly returns error “All channels must be finalized before team”

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've run literally hundreds of test on migrating content into a new team in MS Teams, and all of those tests did /completeMigration on each channel (yes, the General channel too), as well as /completeMigration on the Team itself at the end. This has worked (with a few exceptions that we couldn't explain, but retries fixed that).

But now, all of a sudden (this worked four-five days ago) we're getting this error EVERY time we try and do /completeMigration on the Team:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "All channels must be finalized before team.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-01-23T19:13:19",
      "request-id": "SOME GUID",
      "client-request-id": "SOME GUID"
    }
  }
}
```

We are doing /completeMigration on each channel, and we're getting a 204 code back (which is OK according to docs), no errors in the headers. I've stepped through the code isolated and it passes as it should, except for /completeMigration on the Team.

What have changed? I understand these are Beta APIs, but still. Documentation:

- [Team completeMigration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-completemigration?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)
- [Channel completeMigration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-completemigration?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: Open a support case with Office 365. It's free. That's the quickest way to get this resolved.